# Is there another way to get value directly in drf serializer?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Let's assume we have two model

```
Listing
  
class ListingStatus(models.Model):
    FULL = 0
    AVALIABLE = 1

    STATUS_CATEGORY = (
        (FULL, _("Full")),
        (AVALIABLE, _("AVAIL")),
    )

    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CATEGORY, default=AVALIABLE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.status)
```

In serializer code

```
class ListingStatusSerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ListingStatus
        fields = ["status"]

class ListingSerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
    status = ListingStatusSerializer(source="listingstatus.status")
```

It doesn't work.
I get empty serializer

```
class ListingSerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
    status = ListingStatusSerializer(source="listingstatus")
```

This works but I need to get status value like instance.status.status. it's inefficient

```
class ListingSerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
    status = ListingStatusSerializer(source="listingstatus")

    def get_status(self, instance):
        return instance.listingstatus.status
```

I can achieve what I want with above code , but I want to make sure it's best solution?

Comment: You can also do: `status = serializers.IntegerField(source="listingstatus.status")`

Answer (score 0):

use the `get_field_display` approach.

```
class ListingSerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.CharField(source="get_status_display")
```